# Express + NodeJS Documentation

Tags: node.js, documentation, express

Hi Everyone I am newbie to Express + NodeJS. I come from Java and trying to get caught up on Node now so please be gentle if I ask some basic questions (I have spent the last 2 days catching up on this stuff)

My questions are around documentation.

So when I look through some of the examples present on Express site I see the following

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
 ......
});
```

and sometimes

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res){
 ......
});
```

where is the documentation for me to determine how many paramaters go into the function?? first theres was req, res and next but then it had req and res.

Second question: where is the documentation for what is available on the request and response objects along with other method that are available as part of the framework?

I looked up the documenation here http://expressjs.com/guide.html#req.header() but I can't imagine this is entire doc because i notice methods being used on examples that are not present on this documentation.

Can someone point me to the most commonly used docs for express + nodeJS development? If you can list all the links here I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: You need to slow down a minute. Do you have any experience with another language besides Java? Javascript does not have method signatures in the way you know from Java. Here is a quick example:

```
function foo(bar, baz, qux) {
    var result = bar + baz;
    if(qux) {
        result += qux;
    }
    return result;
}

foo(1, 2);
// => 3
foo(1, 2, 3);
// => 6
```

It's a contrived example, but it shows that you can declare a function which takes 3 arguments, and only use two of them. In fact, it could use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) directly and accept even *more* arguments than specified in the function declaration!

```
function bar(foo) {
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
        var baz = arguments[1];
        return foo + baz;
    }
    return foo;
}

bar(2);
// => 2
bar(2, 4);
// => 6
```

Anyway, in short, your route handler `function(req, res, next) {}` will always be called with `req`, `res`, and `next` -- but it just might be the case that you don't need `next` (because you won't ever pass on control, perhaps), so you omit it (it will still be *there*, in your `arguments` object, just not scoped as `next`). Some feel this is sloppy, others that it's succinct.

Second question: Here is [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/index.html), [http.ServerRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverrequest), [http.ServerResponse](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). You already know the Express guide.

Comment: thanks Linus, i'm reading up on javascript before I completely dive in node. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is kind of lax about the number of parameters a function takes. If a function takes two parameters, you can still pass it five arguments — the first two you pass will go in the named parameters, and the rest will only be available through the `arguments` object. (Similarly, if you write a function that takes three arguments, a caller can still pass only two and the third will have the value `undefined`.)

So basically, the function will always get three arguments, but a lot of times you have no intention of using the `next` continuation, so you can just leave it off and JavaScript will silently swallow it.

As for documentation, that guide is the official documentation for Express. The docs for Node.js are [at nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/). Express's modules are generally based off their vanilla Node equivalents (e.g. the server is based off Node's http.Server).